# $y=3x$ divides the region between $y=1-x^2$ and $y=x^2-1$ into two parts. What is the area of the smaller region?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

> $y=3x$ divides the area enclosed by $y=1-x^2$ and $y=x^2-1$ into two
> parts. What is the area of the smaller region?

First I calculated the area between  $y=1-x^2$ and $y=x^2-1$,

$$S=\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)-(x^2-1)dx=\frac83$$I'm not sure how to continue I tried finding the intersection point of the $y=3x$ with $y=1-x^2$ and $y=x^2-1$ but that doesn't look helpful because it involves irregular numbers.

Comment: "The smaller region"? Hmm.

Comment: @aschepler It was a multiple choice question and the answer key says the correct answer is $\frac43$! A strange question.... After checking the graph It looks the areas are equal. But is it possible to prove $y=ax$ divides the region equally?

Comment: @Etemon Rotational symmetry. Consider what happens if you transform $x\rightarrow -x$ and $y\rightarrow -y$.

Comment: So smaller than the first area enclosed by the two parabolae, not smaller than the other divided part. But confusing wording!